# MCU receive CAN data after a while

Tags: stm32, can

I am using stm32f4 and sensor with my Canbus experiments.

When I transmit canbus data to sensor, sensor send to some data as in below picture( green is Canbus H line, pink is CAN-Rx line) And blue  is, when MCU receive canbus data trigger pin.

this is the Tx block:

```
  if(HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan1,&TxCanOpenHeader,msg,&TxMailbox) != HAL_OK)
    {
      while( HAL_CAN_IsTxMessagePending(&hcan1,TxMailbox));
    }
```

When the below condition works, pin to high.

```
if(HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(&hcan1, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &RxHeader, rcvd_msg) == HAL_OK)
  {    
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(OUTPUT_1_GPIO_Port,OUTPUT_1_Pin,1 ); 
  }
```

When green data comes, MCU detect this data after a while as shown in  label, this time value sometimes 1ms sometimes 2ms randomly, but never detect this data on the line.

Why does this happen?

[image]

Also, CAN_Init() function as in below:

```
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 0 */
  CAN_FilterTypeDef  sFilterConfig;

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 0 */
//APB1 bus clock rate: 45MHZ
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 1 */
  hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
  
    hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 5U;
 

  hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan1.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;

  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_15TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;
  
  hcan1.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 2 */
    /*##-2- Configure the CAN Filter ###########################################*/
  sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
  sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
  sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
  sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 0;

  if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Filter configuration Error */
        SerialPrint("FILTER ERROR !!");

    Error_Handler();
  }

  /*##-3- Start the CAN peripheral ###########################################*/
  if (HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    SerialPrint("CAN START ERROR !!");
    /* Start Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /*##-4- Activate CAN RX notification #######################################*/
if(HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan1,CAN_IT_TX_MAILBOX_EMPTY | CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING |CAN_IT_BUSOFF) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 2 */

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the HAL Rx routine takes a millisecond. Try checking the FMP0 bits in the CAN_RF0R register directly, this will be much faster.

Comment: But, HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage function also check FMP0 bits.

Comment: How often does this code run?

Comment: Are you sure that you can observe the response on the bus? The image is low resolution, so I can't distinguish the request & response. Be aware that RX line also shows the transmitted message. So, maybe there is no received message at all. But in that case, function should return `HAL_ERROR`. Strange...

Comment: @Tagli yes sure, I decode the message. But after another comments when I use the interrrupt Receive method, time is constant and very quick.

Comment: @gogogo Sure it does (after some additional checks which also takes time), but when there is a message received, it also copies this message from the FIFO etc, which takes more time before the function returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage which is polling.

The timing is probably faster and more consistent when using the HAL callbacks, depending on what other higher priority interrupts are pending.

The callbacks work via the bxCAN interrupts.

Comment: I disabled all interrupts on my code, how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: @gogogo There is not a problem. Your code works as intended. IF you want it improved use the callbacks.

Comment: callbacks or interrupt ? If calbacks which callback because CAN have 2 callbacks      (+) HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback
      (+) HAL_CAN_RxFifo0FullCallback there is no message so there only one message and no pending how can I detect with this ?

Comment: Yes, you are right today I try with interrupt and Time approximately 4 us.